Selenium Scrape Issue
I am building a web scraper that scrapes the beatport top 100.
I am having an issue where some items are located, but others get an error.
def scrape_beatport():
    user_agent = UserAgent().random
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument(f"user-agent={user_agent}")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
    
    try:
        driver.get('https://www.beatport.com/top-100')
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div#__next')))
        
        test1 = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div#__next')
        test2 = driver.fin_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.TracksList-style__Wrapper-sc-3fb03d50-8 bWXYsy row')
        

        
    finally:
        driver.quit()


        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    scrape_beatport()    

this is my code. test1 is foud and is a div in the body tag. test2 is much deeper into the html structure. it is inside a bunch of other divs, and when I try to get it, they give me an error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/just/Documents/python/yt_test.py", line 84, in <module>
    scrape_beatport()    
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/just/Documents/python/yt_test.py", line 71, in scrape_beatport
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.__next div.MainLayout-style__MainWrapper-sc-9f30c253-0 div div.MainLayout-style__Main-sc-9f30c253-1 main.MainLayout-style__MainContent-sc-9f30c253-2 div.TracksList-style__Wrapper-sc-3fb03d50-8')))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 105, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 
Stacktrace:
0   chromedriver                        0x0000000105272940 chromedriver + 4368704
1   chromedriver                        0x000000010526add4 chromedriver + 4337108
2   chromedriver                        0x0000000104e8ec04 chromedriver + 289796
3   chromedriver                        0x0000000104ed0e00 chromedriver + 560640
4   chromedriver                        0x0000000104f095ec chromedriver + 792044
5   chromedriver                        0x0000000104ec5ab4 chromedriver + 514740
6   chromedriver                        0x0000000104ec650c chromedriver + 517388
7   chromedriver                        0x0000000105236e5c chromedriver + 4124252
8   chromedriver                        0x000000010523bc4c chromedriver + 4144204
9   chromedriver                        0x000000010521c824 chromedriver + 4016164
10  chromedriver                        0x000000010523c57c chromedriver + 4146556
11  chromedriver                        0x000000010520e2d8 chromedriver + 3957464
12  chromedriver                        0x000000010525bec4 chromedriver + 4275908
13  chromedriver                        0x000000010525c040 chromedriver + 4276288
14  chromedriver                        0x000000010526aa34 chromedriver + 4336180
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000018a0bd034 _pthread_start + 136
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000018a0b7e3c thread_start + 8

Please check out the beatport top 100 yourself to see the html, because it is a lot.
Thanks a lot!

Your code timed out waiting for an element to be present but the locator was not correct, that's why it never appeared.
I've updated your code below and it's working. It pulls the titles of all tracks. If you want to pull more info, make sure you start your search with row, e.g. row.find_element() not driver.find_element().
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

def scrape_beatport():
    # user_agent = UserAgent().random
    # chrome_options = Options()
    # chrome_options.add_argument(f"user-agent={user_agent}")
    # driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    try:
        driver.get('https://www.beatport.com/top-100')
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
        rows = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[data-testid='tracks-table-row']")))
        print(len(rows))
        for row in rows:
            title = row.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[data-testid='marquee-parent']").text
            print(title)
    finally:
        driver.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    scrape_beatport()

Output
100
Waiting For Tonight Extended Mix       
Go Back feat. Julia Church Original Mix
Last Night Anyma x Layton Giordani Extended Remix
It's Not Right But It's Okay Extended
...


Thank you! You're amazing. I was struggling with this issue the past few days, and couldn't find anything. Thank you!

You are welcome. Glad it worked out for you. If this or any other answer was useful please upvote it. Once you find the answer to your question, please mark it as accepted so the question isn't left unanswered.

You can't pass multiple classes separated by spaces to CSS_SELECTOR, but it's possible with XPATH:
This should work:
test2 = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="TracksList-style__Wrapper-sc-3fb03d50-8 bWXYsy row"]')


The class name doesn't include spaces... each class is SEPARATED by spaces. That's the CSS selector syntax.
